# Weird behavior on reverse proxy by htaccess

Tags: proxy, htaccess

I've set up a reverse proxy on my vps by placing the following `.htaccess` file under /var/www/html/ecommerce/app.

```
DirectoryIndex disabled

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000 [P,L]
```

localhost:3000 is the local node server running on my vps.

/var/www/html/ is the document root. So I was expecting, if all goes well, I can load the app via http://my-public-vps-ip/ecommerce/app. But that doesn't work and instead I can load the app via http://my-public-vps-ip:3000.

I don't understand this. Could you help me understand what might be going on?

Comment: define "doesn't work" please. Be more specific of what happens instead.

Comment: the site is not loaded.

Comment: here's error.log. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XD5JMjDxhJ/ it's trying to access files under /var/www/html/* that don't exist. this is when i visit http://my-public-vps-ip/ecommerce/app.